# How would I log every function call the PHP interpreter makes during a given script?

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, logging

Can I configure mod_php, XDebug, or Eclipse (or some other *free* program) to print to file the code that is executed? And if so can I limit it to function calls to keep it somewhat readable?

Comment: By having XDebug profile your application you can view which functions were called - using say KCachegrind. I cannot remember if the execution order is preserved or if it just tallies them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) for that, and [webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/) to view the results.

Comment: Excellent. I'm already using XDebug. I knew it had to have some kind of logging.